# Why is my Grid Tapped event not being called?

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps, grid-layout

It's true that I'm not actually tapping in the simulator - as my dev machine is not touch-enabled - but I don't think that's the problem, as my clicking within the grid should fire the event.

Here's my xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1" Margin="24,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Tapped="Grid_OnTapped">
```

...and my code:

```
private void Grid_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs args)
{
     if (args.OriginalSource.Equals(grid1))
     {
    . . .
```

I never make it to the Grid_OnTapped event. What am I missing?

Comment: Tapped is also called if clicked with mouse... Try setting `Background="Transparent"`. Maybe you should show some code inside the grid...

Comment: That was it; make it an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Set `Background="Transparent"` in your `Grid`.

Comment: Yes it works, but can you add some detail as to why?